# How to use COUNTIFS with AND and text

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use COUNTIFS with text and the logical operator AND in Google Spreadsheet, but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is my current formula, which counts everything. I just want to know the count if it meets these three criteria. That is: The person is from **North America** OR **Europe** AND has signed up for the session **Intentions, Constraints and Goal-Setting**.

Any help would be much appreciated!

`=SUM(COUNTIFS('IMP CRM'!O:O,"*North America*"),COUNTIFS('IMP CRM'!O:O,"*Europe*"),COUNTIFS('IMP CRM'!P:P,"*Intentions, Constraints and Goal-Setting*"))`

Comment: Thanks so much! That solved it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(O:O,(REGEXMATCH(O:O,"North America|Europe")) * (REGEXMATCH(P:P,"Intentions, Constraints and Goal-Setting"))))`

Notes:

- "*" in boolean logic means `AND` logic, like "+" means `OR`
- pip "|" in regex means `OR` logic

References:

1. [`Filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
2. [`regexmatch`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)
3. [reguler expressions syntax.](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)